# Why the same code will differ by 3 times in performance in viewDidLoad and delay task

Tags: objective-c, performance

I am testing the layout performance of TextKit on iPhone7 iOS13，but I found that the same code has different performance.

Test code can be seen below，the time spent in the test method of viewDidLoad is 0.305ms, 0.082ms, 0.062ms respectively and the time spent in the delay task is 1.018ms, 0.425ms, 0.462ms.

I have reduced the code in the test method, this problem still exists, this problem has nothing to do with TextKit.

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Demo";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [self test];
    [self test];
    [self test];

    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // Each test call takes more than 3 times more time than the test call in viewDidLoad
        [self test];
        [self test];
        [self test];
    });
}


- (void)test
{
    NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTextContainer* textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] init];
    textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[];


    NSLayoutManager * layoutManager = [NSLayoutManager new];
    layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false;
    layoutManager.hyphenationFactor = 0;
    layoutManager.showsInvisibleCharacters = false;
    layoutManager.showsControlCharacters = false;
    layoutManager.usesFontLeading = true;
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

    NSTextStorage* textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:@"h"];

    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    NSTimeInterval endTime = [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSLog(@"Test generate cost in %f ms", (endTime - startTime) * 1000.0);
}
```

I am eager to know what caused the difference in performance.

Comment: What are you doing inside the test method?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to post the code. I have updated the code.